# gnome-shell span_command_line_sync command is giving numerical values instead of text

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

when I run the command `uname-r` in gnome-terminal.
I get the result as `6.6.1-arch-1`.

```
$ uname -r
6.6.1-arch1-1
$
```

I have created a gnome-shell-extension inside which I am calling the command below

```
const obj = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('uname -r');
Main.notify('', JSON.stringify(obj)); // testing purpose
const kernelText = `Kernel Version ${obj[1].toString().trim()}`;
```

The obj I am getting is like this

[image]

How can I get the text with out this line,

```
const kernelText = `Kernel Version ${obj[1].toString().trim()}`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GLib.spawn_command_line_sync()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/glib20%7E2.0/glib.spawn_command_line_sync) returns an array of four values: a success boolean, stdout as a `Uint8Array`, stderr as a `Uint8Array` and the wait status as a `Number`.

There is a guide for [Spawning Subprocesses](https://gjs.guide/guides/gio/subprocesses.html) in GJS, or you may want to use [`GLib.get_os_info()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/glib20%7E2.0/glib.get_os_info) if you're using it to spawn `uname`.

Spawning a synchronous subprocess in an extension is highly discouraged and will probably not pass review.